# Replace the customized configuration file..?

Tags: upgrade

upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.1. Prompted with *Replace the customized configuration file '/etc/default/rcS'?*

I am not sure what to do, keep or replace..? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`/etc/default/rcS`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/rcS.5.html) file affects the behavior of the boot scripts.  You can use the installation process to look at the difference between the two files if you are not sure if you have made any changes to the file.

When I'm not sure about a configuration file I usually drop into a shell and copy that file to something similar to `rcS.old`, then allow the overwrite so that I can later examine the changes and use both to create my best configuration file between the two.

Of course the options are:
(Example prompt)

```
Configuration file `/etc/bash.bashrc'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** bash.bashrc (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

Comment: okay, what commands would I run to copy that file to a new location in case something happens that shouldn't? And then I can go ahead and overwrite, choosing **replace**, correct?

Comment: @KyleDrummond There are a few ways.  I usually hit `ALT+CTL+F2`  to drop into a shell.  But as you can see from the default prompt, it gives and option `Z` to start a shell to examine the situation.

Comment: okay, I don't have an option *Z*  like the post above, but how do I copy the old file to a new location? Still new to Ubuntu a little and I don't want to mess this up.

Comment: @KyleDrummond After hitting `ALT-CTL-F2` to get a console prompt you could run `cp /etc/defaults/rcS ~/rcS.old`.  Or you could make a backupfolder and copy the file to your backup folder such as `cp /etc/defaults/rcS ~/configfolder/`.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will run the first command in terminal, then just hit **replace**?

Comment: @KyleDrummond A pleasure... if it works consider placing the check mark to the answer so that others can see a workable resolution to similar questions.

Comment: hmm, I tried **cp /etc/defaults/rcS ~/rcS.old** and it said no such file or directory... Anyways, this was a fresh install of 14.04 on it, didn't feel like flashing a new iso, I'm assuming I won't need to worry too much about the configuration file change it's asking about, now how do i exit the terminal?

Comment: @KyleDrummond Check for the exact file name with `ls /etc/defaults/`.

Comment: @KyleDrummond Sorry... I typed in the check and got the error... it should be `/etc/default/rcS`.  The directory `defaults` was a mistype.  It should be `default`.

Comment: ahh, I should have caught that. Worked! And then to exit the terminal, how do I do that with this one?

Comment: @you can type `exit` to exit the terminal.  You can get back to your GUI session by hitting `ALT+CTRL+F7`.